# Subprocess calls the wrong version of 'time'

Tags: python, linux, shell, time, subprocess

I'm trying to call the shell keyword version of 'time' via

```
subprocess.check_output('time ls',stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
```

this is giving me the output (which is /usr/bin/time output):

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1992maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+85minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

rather than the shell keyword output:

```
real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

For some reason subprocess.check_output is using the /usr/bin/time version of time.

Could someone tell me what is happening here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `time` is a also a built in function in Bash. So you need to specify that you want to use Bash as your shell:

```
print subprocess.check_output('time ls', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,\
    shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually fixed this by appending 'bash -c' to the start of my commands to put through subprocess but this way is better.